# Facebook iOS SK initial version broken

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have over half-a-dozen apps with Facebook integration. They all used the old Facebook iOS SDK (prior to the sing-sign-on version of their sdk). Everything worked fine for the last year or so. Now, all apps report the error: "action links must have strings 'href' and 'text' attributes," which is a total bs since they do and it has worked.

When I remove the action-links (from Xcode and run), things work fine except that the "user_message_prompt" text is ignored (i.e. no customized message presented to the user). So, has facebook basically decided to force everyone to update to their latest sdk or am I missing something? I am surprised that I didn't find many such complaints.

I know, if I am going to release an upgrade, I will just migrate to the latest version (I hate to be forced to upgrade every time a third party decides to release upgrade to their sdk though).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.  As of July 12th, this value is being ignored.  The SDK no longer allows you to pre-populate this field:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

The only other option is to use your own custom dialogs and utilize the graph API to post the update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which field are you talking about? user_message_prompt or action_links? What's really making the post fail is the inclusion of the action_links (I can live without the user message prompt). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into the same error message with the old (2.x) SDK. In my case, it turned out that the original `name` and `link` action fields were fine, I just had to make sure the `link` is not the empty string, and voila!